# aggregation and indexing based on specific column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a csv file related to world happiness data by country. In that data file different scores related to happiness are calculated based on some specific criteria. i want to find the worst and best countries based on these criteria(characteristics). My solution to this is given below with notebook pictures:

```
happiness_df = pd.read_csv('Datasets/happiness_2017.csv')
happiness_data_by_country = {}
for column in happiness_df.describe().columns:
    if column != 'Rank':       
        max_val = happiness_df.describe().loc['max',column]
        min_val = happiness_df.describe().loc['min',column]
        country_with_max = happiness_df.loc[happiness_df[column]==max_val,'Country'].values[0]
        country_with_min = happiness_df.loc[happiness_df[column]==min_val,'Country'].values[0]
        happiness_data_by_country[column] = {
        "worst" : country_with_min,
        "best" : country_with_max 
    }
```

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Vuo.png)

[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMiEA.png)

is there any better way of doing this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for the maximum value you can try:

df.loc[df['HappinessScore'].idxmax()]

And for the minimum: df.loc[df['HappinessScore'].idxmin()].

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the idxmin,idxmax function.